# How to match index of an element from a list of list and return result (an element doesnot have similar length as others) in Python?

Tags: python, list, indexing, split, element

I have a very big txt file. I want to read through each line of the file and get an input based on the 3rd element of the file(list).

So, I convert the text file to list and iterate through each element of the list to get my desired output.

This is a part of my txt file:

```
34566---There was no file in there---Mr. Gonsalves---gns@gmail.com

36122---I found the file in system---Johny---jhn@gmail.com

64322

28890---I went to see the crowd---Henry Fields---hnfl@gmail.com

44533---The weather made it perfect---Merry Vol---mvol@gmail.com
```

This is the code that I used:

```
value = input("Enter your name:")

filename = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in filename:
  line_num = line.strip('\n').split("---")
  if line_num [2] == value:
     print(line_num[1])
     break
```

The only problem is the value in the middle doesnot behave as the other elements in the list. So, it is giving an error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know how to code to ignore the middle element which doesnot behave as the rest of the elements in the list. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
value = input("Enter your name:")

filename = open("anotherSix.txt", "r")
for line in filename:
    if line == '\n':
        continue
    line_num = line.strip('\n').split("---")
    if line_num [2] == value:
        print(line_num[1])
        break
```

As You can see I added only the `if line == '\n': continue` part which basically skips the empty line

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition to:

```
if len(line_num) > 2 and line_num [2] == value:
```